# Atmega 328pu as stand alone

Tags: atmega328, relay

I am used atmega 328pu as stand alone.i used 7805 as regulator.
I regulated from 12 VOLT 2 amp smps.

When I connect my dc 12 VOLT pump in between 12 VOLT and ground dc motor working fine but Atmega stops working.

Please help me with this.

EDIT: Information added from the comments.

Q: Does the Arduino work with the motor disconnected?

A: Yes it's works fine

[image]

Comment: The first thing is that you have no decoupling capacitors.

Comment: Where I need to put decoupling capacitor .can you please send a diagram if possible.

Comment: Also 7805 might be unstable without input and output capacitors.

Comment: perhaps the pump drops the voltage below 5v? seems a long-shot, but if the PSU is massively over-loaded that can happen.

Comment: I used two 10uf/63 volt capacitor with 7805 in the input and out put.still I have the problem.

Comment: When connected pump at the same time I measured the voltage it is still 5 volt.

Comment: Perhaps your circuit sketch is different from reality, but: The GND signals should not be connected to a bus type line. especially Pin 8, 22 and 22pF crystal cap GND should be directly connected with short wires and have only one connection to the 12V GND and 7805 GND

Answer (score 1):

Add 0.1uF caps from pin 7 to 8, and from pin 20 to 22. Keep them close to the chip.
If you will be doing any analogRead()s, then add one from 21 to 22 as well.